# CSS drop down menu not appearing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been working on this and I think something is conflicting. I can't get the drop down menu to actually work. I think the hovers on the `btn-acc` might be conflicting but when I remove it, it doesn't seem to help.

The drop down menu, is not currently correctly formatted, I figured I would format that when it actually worked. Any help to make the list simply pop up when I hover over the account button?

```
    <div id="fb-root"><span class="panel">
      <ul class="main">             
            <li><a class="btn-acc" href="#">Account</a></li>
                <ul class="account">
                    <li>My Account</li> 
                    <li>Prefrences</li> 
                    <li>Options</li> 
                    <li>Submit a Recipe</li> 
                    <li>Forum</li> 
                    <li>About Us</li>
                </ul> 
            <li><a class="btn-logout" href="#">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
            </span>
            </div>


/*--CSS Starts HERE ----------*/

    .main {
    text-align: left;
     display: inline;
}
.main li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: realtive;
}

    #fb-root {
        text-align: right;
        padding:9px 12px;
        border-bottom: thin;
        border-color: black;
        }

    #fb-root .btn-acc {
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 0 solid #01060E;
        background-color: #BAC6D7;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #F7F7F7;
        padding: 8px 15px
    }

    #fb-root .btn-acc:hover,
    #fb-root .btn-acc:active {
        color: #F7F7F7;
        background: #2c3f52;
    }


        .btn-logout {
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;  
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 0 solid #01060E;
            background-color: #BAC6D7;
            text-align: center;
            color: #F7F7F7;
            padding: 8px 15px
        }

        .btn-logout:hover,
        .btn-logout:active {
            color: #F7F7F7;
            background: #2c3f52;
        }
        .account {
          padding: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: 48px;
          left: 0;
          width: 150px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          -moz-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
          display: none;
          opacity: 0;
          visibility: hidden;
          -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
          -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -transition: opacity 0.2s;
        }

        #fb-root .btn-acc:hover .account{
            display:block;
            opacity:1;
            visibility: visible;    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

## [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/p8278u11/)

You're missing two small things.

1. You closed your `li` before your nested `ul`, which makes the whole element invalid HTML.  The `li` should wrap your `ul`
2. You need to define the `:hover` as a sibling rule, as `.account` isn't a child of your button.  Like so:

```
#fb-root .btn-acc:hover + .account{ /*This line changed*/
  display:block;
  opacity:1;
  visibility: visible;    
 }
```

Comment: Beat me to it, this is correct ... for more information on why this is correct read the following article, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are using wrong selector for hover.
your .account class is nested under other li tag  not in a tag and you trying to apply hover on inside a tag

1. first remove class **.btn-acc** from a and add it to li
2. then change the last selector to this

   ```
       #fb-root .btn-acc:hover + .account{
               display:block;
               opacity:1;
               visibility: visible;    
           }
   ```

here is your working solution

http://jsbin.com/kateletisu/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without absolute positioning if you're clever. (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) Otherwise you'll need a pseudo-class on your popup menu so it doesn't disappear.
Try this:

```
    #fb-root .acc-menu .account{
        width: 150px;
        display:none;
    }
    #fb-root .acc-menu:hover .account{
        display:inline-block;
        opacity:1;
    }

    <li class="acc-menu">
        <a class="btn-acc" href="#">Account</a>
        <div class="account">
            <ul>
                <li>My Account</li> 
                <li>Prefrences</li> 
                <li>Options</li> 
                <li>Submit a Recipe</li> 
                <li>Forum</li> 
                <li>About Us</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </li>
```

It's important to keep in mind that when you're dealing with HTML/CSS you need to think about the document structure and the CSS styles at the same time. Even if your selectors match up in both cases the child elements inherit parent styles and are constricted by their parents' sizes. Add * {border: solid 1px; } until you're sure it's right. If you can avoid sibling selectors that's even better. Older browsers can have trouble with them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your submenu needs to be inside the `<li>`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3xgt4st/1/)